# Mootools 1.4.5 Request 'encoding' option not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, character-encoding, mootools

I'm trying to force an 'ISO-8859-1' charset on my ajax request header but for some reason I can't get it to change from "UTF-8".  I've got the following...

```
var request = new Request({
    url: url,
    method: 'post',
    data: params,
    encoding: 'ISO-8859-1',
    onSuccess: function(textResponse, xmlResponse) {
            //success func
        },
        onFailure: function(xhr) {
            //fail func
        }
    }).send();
```

Even after configuring that setting, my Request Header's content-type shows "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" in Chrome's Developer Tools.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It does work. 1 tiny problem: the code path for setting the charset is behind another variable - `urlEncoded: true` needs to be set.

see https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Request/Request.js#L175-L178

and a jsfiddle to demo this: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/3qazx/

```
new Request({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        html: '<p>Text echoed back to request</p>',
        delay: 0
    },
    method: 'post',
    urlEncoded: true,
    encoding: 'ISO-8859-1',
    onComplete: function(){
        $('target').set('html', this.response.text);
    }
}).send();
```

I'd argue the documentation is unclear of the relation between the two - http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request#Request

it says it but meh:

> - `urlEncoded` - (`boolean`: defaults to true) If set to true, the `content-type` header is set to `www-form-urlencoded` + `encoding`
> - `encoding` - (string: defaults to `utf-8`) The encoding to be set in the request header.

the latter needs 'ignored when urlEncoded not true'

Comment: Hmmm... with the JSFiddle example you provided, I'm still showing "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" in Chrome's dev tools. Also, isn't `urlEncoded` set to `true` by default?  I think you also have a typo in your configuration -- you've written the option as `urlEncoding` instead of `urlEncoded`.  But... even when I change to `urlEncoded` it still doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send%28%29-method - it's being rejected by the browser. I could have sworn it was working - even had a screenshot in my clipboard and then chose not to bother. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455850 - having said that, if you look at http://jsfiddle.net/yzU26/, it is 100% correct w/o mootools in both FF and Chrome. very very odd. would you mind raising this on the mootools issue tracker so they can look at it before 1.5 release. thanks!

Comment: `Let the request entity body be the result of running the multipart/form-data encoding algorithm with data as form data set and with utf-8 as the explicit character encoding.`